# Any Windows based OpenID servers out there?

Tags: windows, openid

I've been looking to setup an OpenID server for a special project, but haven't found any workable OpenID server software packages.  Originally was looking for a *nix solution, and found several, but they all had some kind of issue.

So far I've tried JOIDS, community-id, and a couple others I unfortunately can't remember the names of.

I've also come to the conclusion that even if I had managed to get one of those going that the management/upgrade cycles would have placed undue burden on the company (only a couple part time sysadmins with *nix knowledge, the day to day people are primarily Windows). So, I'm hoping that there's a Windows one out that will be functional that someone knows about and will be easy for a minimal support environment...

Comment: DO you want this OpenID server to authenticate users against Active Directory?

Comment: Product recommendations and shopping questions are off-topic, per the [faq]

Comment: @MDMarra isn't he just looking for a tool?  We don't suggest those?

Comment: @uSlackr No, that's a product recommendation. It's explicitly off-topic.

Comment: How is it different than this question? (trying to understand the subtlety ) http://serverfault.com/questions/376846/api-management-solutions

Comment: I'd vote to close that too, but I can't since it has a bounty on it. If you have a question like this, you should post on [meta] where the whole community can take a peek.

Comment: I was afraid it might be found to be off-topic, but I don't have any other ideas on how to find one that works.  So far everything I've run across is unusable/broken in some fundamental way.  :-(  Oh well, with the security issues with OpenID perhaps it's a bad idea to use it anyways.

Answer (score 2):

openid usually runs at the web application level so is os-independent. since most web apps such as php, python, ruby all run on windows, you should be run one, though i have not done so.

http://wiki.openid.net/w/page/12995226/Run%20your%20own%20identity%20server